# Excel 2007 VBA Code- Splitting Cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell, split

Excel 2007- I have countless old Word Tables that I'd like to put into Excel.  I'd like to split the contents of the cell into two cells.  Most of the cells have a very similar format (I don't need to split the ones without this format)- Text (Date).  I've tried using "LEFT" or "RIGHT" but since the text string and date string are variable lengths there are no good straightforward ways.  For example-

Cell A1- 
"Market Value (6/16/09)" [or "Addition (12/15/09)", etc.]

I'd like to split the cell into-

Cell A1- "Market Value" and
Cell B1- "6/16/09"

Obviously if it takes the A1 data and puts it into B1/C1 I could care less.

I've seen some other split VBA modules but they don't seem to be doing the trick for me.  I've looked for ways to split it using CSV but that doesn't seem to be useful either.  So is there a way to use the "(" or ")" as a marker to copy text before or after the "("?

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to use the "(" or ")" as a marker to copy text before or after the "("?

Yes

Example

Cell A1- "Market Value (6/16/09)"

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar() As String

    Ar = Split(Range("A1").Value, "(")

    Debug.Print Ar(0) '<~~ This will give      Market Value
    Debug.Print Ar(1) '<~~ This will give      6/16/09)

    '<~~ And the below will give you           6/16/09
    Debug.Print Replace(Ar(1), ")", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I think.  I am a newbie so still working on the language/objects/processes.  Thank you!